# Card view bootstrap

Tags: c#, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I am applying responsive grid layout for this card view.My project is in .net MVC4 c#.

**Before narrow screen** layout is -
[image: Card view of contacts]

**After narrow screen**-

[image]

Here is result after i do narrow screen, I have addressed bootstrap responsive css in layout. This list is being fetched out from database.

LIST-

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">



         <div class="span3" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:4px;cursor:pointer;" Onclick="Contact_List_CardEdit('@Url.Contact_PartialView_Main()?ContactID=${ContactID}')">
           <address class="well">
                <strong>${DisplayName}</strong><br/>
                <em>${Email1}</em><br/>
                <em>${PhoneOffice}</em><br/>
                <em>${Address}</em><br/>
                </address>

                </div>

</script>
 </div>   
        </div>
```

I want responsive layout for this view **when i do narrow screen**. Kendo UI is for list view here.

Comment: You don't seem to use any `.row` wrapper

Comment: Also, I wouldn't mess with left/right margins on `span*` elements

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set style in CSS responsive file like

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .hidden-desktop {
       display: inherit !important;
    }
 }
```

Or you can catch width of screen via JavaScript and set only two columns.
I solved it by setting normal container and put fluid class to a row, like this.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span3">
         Some_code_here
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
         Some_code_here
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
         Some_code_here
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
         Some_code_here
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```